# Logic Translation

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, logic-translation

> "**a** *and* **e** *are both larger than* **c**, *but neither is large*"

I thought the translation
$$\large (\text{Larger}(a, c)\land \text{Larger}(e, c))\land\lnot(\text{Large}(a)\land \text{Large}(e))$$
would be correct but I am told that it is not. Does anyone know what it would be? The main part of the question, which includes this sentences with others, was to use the translation of

*If* **P**, *then* **Q**

translates as
$$\textbf{P}\rightarrow\textbf{Q}$$

---

Based on comments, the answer would then be
$$\large (\text{Larger}(a, c)\land \text{Larger}(e, c))\land\lnot(\text{Large}(a)\lor\text{Large}(e))$$

Comment: NO; "neither" is ["neither ... nor ..."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_NOR) i.e. $\lnot A \land \lnot E$.

Comment: Ahh so would the changes I've made suffice? @MauroALLEGRANZA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Neither is Foo" means "Not (Either One is Foo)" means "Both are Not Foo," so the second part of your clause should read,

$$\lnot\text{Large}(a)\land\lnot\text{Large}(e)$$

which can be derived from the "Not (Either One is Foo)" by De Morgan's laws,

$$\lnot(\text{Large}(a)\lor\text{Large}(e))$$

Comment: Ahh yes DeMorgan's law on what @MauroALLEGRANZA mentioned in his comment. Thanks!